# zsh completion and unknow bzr commands

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, bazaar

ZSH's Bazaar completion does not offer any expansion/completion when it does not know the `bzr` subcommand I am using. In my case, I use `bzr qlog` but ZSH's `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.2/functions/_bzr` does not know about this command. As far as I can tell it ends up returning nothing from completion function:

```sh
(*)
    _message "unknown bzr command completion: $cmd"
    return 1
    ;;
```

At this point I have employed a hack like this to make it complete with file names:

```sh
(*)
    _message "unknown bzr command completion: $cmd"
    args+=( '*:FILE:_files' )
    #return 1
    ;;
```

Is there any better way how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The 2011 zsh-workers thread “PATCH: Fall back to file completion if nothing else works”](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00959.html) (which discusses the same issue with git) seems to indicate that the completion function indeed needs to be patched to support this behavior.

You can configure the completion system to systematically try files if the fancy completion system finds no completions.

```
zstyle :completion::::: completer _complete _files
```

(Documentation reference: [`zstyle` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle), its [pattern argument](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-1), the [`completer` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-completer_002c-completion-style); aspirin sold separately.)

Unfortunately, this style is global, you can't restrict it to a specific function. (I think.)

You could use a custom function that checks the current command instead of `_files` and only call `_files` is you notice that the command is `bzr`.

Another way to handle this situation is to have a separate key to complete files. You can use the predefined widget [`_bash_complete-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fbash_005fcompletions) which completes different types of object based on the last character of the key sequence.

```
bindkey '^X!' _bash_complete-word # commands
bindkey '^X$' _bash_complete-word # variables
bindkey '^X@' _bash_complete-word # hosts
bindkey '^X/' _bash_complete-word # files
bindkey '^X~' _bash_complete-word # users
```

Or you can define your own widget.

```
zle -C complete_files .complete-word _files
bindkey '^X/' complete_files
```